# How to keep the server socket alive after client abruptly disconnects?

Tags: java, sockets

The once the client disconnects and I restart the client, the server gives read line timeout. and when I run the server again, it works fine. So after disconnect one time I get read line timeout exception and next time it works.

```
import java.io.*;

public class TcpServer {

    ServerSocket welcomeSocket;

    public TcpServer() throws IOException{

        createSocket(port);
    }

    public TcpServer(int port) throws IOException{

        createSocket(port);
    }

    private void createSocket(int port) throws IOException{

        welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

    }

    @Override
    public void listen() throws IOException{

        boolean exitServer = false;
        Socket connectionSocket = null;

        try {
            while (!exitServer ) {
                    if(...){
                    exitServer = true;
                }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

           try {
               welcomeSocket.accept();
               listen();
           } catch (IOException e1) {
               System.out.println("Cannot open connection!!!");
           }

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that is the way the client-server architecture is modelled. If you keep the server socket alive after a client disconnects, what behaviour do you expect from that socket? Every time the client disconnects and tries to reconnect, a new request to the server has to be made.

Comment: I will be fine if I will have to just make a new request to connect. But when the client disconnects abruptly it is causing server to close too. So to make a new request, I will have to actually start the server again. This is not a threaded server. :(

Comment: I think @DV88's answer below would help you better.

Comment: This server code never 'gives read line timeout', as it never reads a line. And `welcomeSocket.accept();` doens't make any sense unless you store the returned `Socket` somewhere and do some I/O with it. As your code presently is, there is nothing a client can do that will disrupt this server. Unclear therefore what you're asking.

Comment: in the while loop of the server when it receives a connection request from client and gets connected to the client, it starts sending a stream of data (characters) using an infinite loop. So when client gets tired of the char sequences it has to just disconnect. and when client disconnects the socket still has data in it, causing client to send a RST to server causing server to reset. and it is the catch{} where I am trying to start the server again but it is causing what I stated earlier. it is the catch statement which is the problem. Which is probably not a right concept either.

Comment: I guess the simple question would be, How can I keep the server alive after the client disconnects with a RST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ServerSocket.accept() method blocks and returns a new client socket connection when someone tries to connect. Put it in a while loop and then spawn a thread for this new socket worker. Something similar to this:

```
 ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
 while (true) {
     Socket socket = welcomeSocket.accept();
     new Thread(new RunnableSocketWorker(socket));
 }
```

If your client does decide to disconnect, that's fine, let them. You *want* the socket worker that was working on it to exit. If a new client tries to connect, they will do so above with your ServerSocket object and this infinite loop.

A big reason sockets are relatively easy in Java is that this ServerSocket class handles all incoming new clients. Why would you want to code that part yourself?

Just take the socket it returns and have fun!